# The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG E1A62E2170B0FA98 Ruslan Askarov <askarru@gmail.com>

Tags: linux, ubuntu, github, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-20.04

```
Err:19 https://deskcap.blob.core.windows.net/deployment/Linux/deb/Release bionic InRelease                                                                                                                        
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG E1A62E2170B0FA98 Ruslan Askarov <askarru@gmail.com>
Fetched 1,598 B in 7s (215 B/s)                                                                                                                                                                                   
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
130 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://deskcap.blob.core.windows.net/deployment/Linux/deb/Release bionic InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG E1A62E2170B0FA98 Ruslan Askarov <askarru@gmail.com>
W: Failed to fetch https://deskcap.blob.core.windows.net/deployment/Linux/deb/Release/dists/bionic/InRelease  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG E1A62E2170B0FA98 Ruslan Askarov <askarru@gmail.com>
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

The error looks like this. What program is this?
Is there a way to convert this invalid signature into a valid one.

Comment: Keep in mind that questions on this site should be about *"specific coding, algorithm, or language problems."* The way this question is phrased, at least, it is about *configuration* and would likely be better suited for [Super User](https://superuser.com) or the [Unix & Linux Stack](https://unix.stackexchange.com).  I would recommend deleting it here and reposting it on a more appropriate site. Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I've downloaded this [file](https://deskcap.blob.core.windows.net/deployment/Linux/deb/Release/dists/bionic/InRelease) and discovered this:
`Origin: Monitask Label: monitask Codename: bionic Date: Sun, 23 Apr 2023 22:33:20 UTC Architectures: amd64 Components: main Description: Monitask repository`
Looks like it from monitask time tracker.